# CI for difference

Tags: confidence-interval

If you build confidence interval for difference (for example, when you are comparing shares), and 0 is included, it means, that the difference is not significant. But can you say something about this difference, using its left and right boundaries? Or these boundaries are meaningful only if they both are the same side from zero?

Comment: You can whether say your confidence interval is narrow or wide.  If it is narrow and is *close* to zero (whether or not it includes zero) this might might lead you to think the difference could be *small* in some sense

Comment: The confidence interval won't be informative if it includes zero but the standard error of the estimate will be. Having a very small CI including zero is still better than having a very large one.